# is there a way to install Qt4 for Python 2.7 under Raspbian Buster on Raspberry Pi 4B

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian, qt4

is there a way to install Qt4 for Python 2.7 under Raspbian Buster on Raspberry Pi 4B. pip is not working, conda ist not working, any sugestions?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Qt4 is in the main repositories for Raspbian. You can install using the command `apt install qt4 -y`